# Modular Exponentiation when only mod of a value is known

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am trying to calculate $A^A$ % mod, where mod is $10^9 + 7$. I can calculate ($A$ % mod) for any value of mod but don't have direct access to A. How would I solve this?

Comment: fermat's little theorem

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p=10^9+7$ and $a=A \bmod p$. This answer also assumes $\gcd(A,p)=1$.

Since $p\in\mathbb{P}$, $\phi(p)=p-1$ and therefore $a^{p-1}=1  \bmod p$.

Now let $b=A\bmod(p-1)$

Therefore $A^A\bmod p=a^b\bmod p$.

There are more efficient algorithms than above for modular exponentiation such as those discussed at the following link.

[Wikipedia Article on Modular Exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation)